# What testing framework/unit testing to use with Delphi XE Starter Edition

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm looking at moving from Delphi 2007 (purchased by my employer) to Delphi XE Starter Edition (purchased by me because my employer is moving away from Delphi) for some open source/hobby work.  So, price is definitely a concern.

Delphi XE Starter Edition doesn't appear to have the integrated DUnit stuff.  Are there any recommendations for testing frameworks that will work well with XE Starter?  The framework must be automatible; for example, it must must be runnable by a Continuous Integration System such as Hudson or CruiseControl.  Of course, free would be best.  Integration directly into the IDE would also be handy, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DUNIT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dunit/develop) is on SourceForge so you can get it from there. The version on SF is 9.4.0, the same that ships with Delphi XE. The code is however not identical. I do not know if it works with Delphi XE Starter edition but I don't see why it should not.

Comment: 9.4.0 is of August 2008. With seven commits in 2009, four commits in 2010, this projects looks rather quiet now.

Comment: @mjn: It works fine.  So why would it get changed?  Personally I'd like to write my own dUnit replacement, because I don't like the GUI version of the test runner.  Am I the only one?

Answer (score 2):

Will DUnit2 do?

Dunit2 is used in tiOPF framework and said to be quite good. The download sites are:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dunit2/

http://members.optusnet.com.au/~mcnabp/

http://github.com/graemeg/dunit2

Comment: The main benefit I see over stock DUnit (from the user perspective) is that it reports memory leaks in each test independently. I use it for that reason, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[DUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dunit/develop) may be a better choice that DUnit2.  With DUnit you can use the jcl and USE_JEDI_JCL to [get the line numbers of failures](http://sourceitsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-line-numbers-in-dunit-test.html).  DUnit2 doesn't appear to support this.

DUNit2 doesn't seem to be getting much attention since Peter's death either.  I don't know if it has been updated to use the latest version of delphi but it doesn't look like it.